# How to change value of cell in one column, when you have duplicate cells across two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a `pandas` dataframe consisting of address fields for columns. My problem is that across two columns, I have duplicate cell values across the row. Does anybody know how I can conditionally change the value for one column when a duplicate is found across the two columns? Ideally I would like to keep one value, and set the other to `np.nan`.

Here is a test case:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_json('{"housename":{"16":null,"17":null,"18":null},"name":{"16":"Shoecare","17":"33","18":"33A"},"house_number":{"16":"32","17":"33","18":"33A"},"street":{"16":"Carfax","17":"Carfax","18":"Carfax"},"city":{"16":"Horsham","17":"Horsham","18":"Horsham"},"postcode":{"16":"RH12 1EE","17":"RH12 1EE","18":"RH12 1EE"}}')

    city        house_number    housename   name        postcode    street
16  Horsham     32              NaN         Shoecare    RH12 1EE    Carfax
17  Horsham     33              NaN         33          RH12 1EE    Carfax
18  Horsham     33A             NaN         33A         RH12 1EE    Carfax
```

On the test case, I've played with `test.duplicated(subset=['house_number', 'name'])`, but it won't identify duplicate values in the `house_number` and `name` columns.

Does anybody have any suggestions of how to firstly identify duplicated cells across two columns, and then set one value to `np.nan`?

Desired output:

```
    housename   name      house_number  street  city     postcode
16  NaN         Shoecare  32            Carfax  Horsham  RH12 1EE
17  NaN         NaN       33            Carfax  Horsham  RH12 1EE
18  NaN         NaN       33A           Carfax  Horsham  RH12 1EE
```

Comment: So what you're looking for is detecting where `house_number` and `name` have the same value? You can achieve that doing: `test[test.name==test.house_number]`. If you want to change the value of one of the columns, let's say `name`, you can do `test.loc[test.name==test.house_number, 'name'] = np.nan`

Comment: Could you provide a desired output so that we can see exactly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2 columns are `house_number` and `name`, you can do in this way:

```
test['name'] = np.where((test['house_number'] == test['name']), np.nan, test['name'])
```

Output:

```
       city house_number  housename      name  postcode  street
16  Horsham           32        NaN  Shoecare  RH12 1EE  Carfax
17  Horsham           33        NaN       NaN  RH12 1EE  Carfax
18  Horsham          33A        NaN       NaN  RH12 1EE  Carfax
```

Comment: Or... `test['name'].where(test['house_number'] != test['name'], np.nan, inplace=True)` ?